# Visual Studio 2017 has lost basic references

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, reference, visual-studio-2017

I have a project on VS2017 that is mixing VB.NET and C#. I was working on some VB files when suddendly all reference were lost. Now it doesn't recognise basic types like Exception, StringBuilder and DateTime. This happens in all the VB files, but not in the C# ones.
I've already tried Clean Solution, various rebuild and removing Visual Studio's cache.

Comment: are you sing resharper ?

Comment: No, I'm not using any particular extension.

Comment: If you create a new VB project does it have the same problem? (Also, how were you mixing languages in a single project in the first place?)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever New projects does not have this issue, as well as other projects already in that solution.

Comment: But how are you mixing languages in a single project?

Comment: Some of my older coworkers setupped things, and now I can add C# files (edit: classes) in a specific folder. Some handlers are in C#, but most of the project are VB classes and webforms with VB codebehind.
Edit: basically VB don't use C# classes, but C# can use VB ones.

Comment: `Now it doesn't recognise basic types like Exception, StringBuilder and DateTime.` Show us the first 15 lines of an impacted file.

Comment: Why not just put C# in its own project and add a project reference? The bottom line is that Visual Studio isn't meant to be used that way. Yes, people have hacked together ways to make it work but it's a very bad idea. There are User Voice suggestions requesting official support for this going back to about 2010, which also suggests MS isn't very interested in adding this, probably because language incompatibilities would cause more trouble than it's worth (for example, C# has `unsafe` but VB has no equivalent concept).

Comment: Open Rosyln [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/21024) for anyone interested in why it works at all, and the difficulties around adding official support.